# Hide div element depending on value passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page has a table which has been populated with many records. Behind each record is an sID and CarersReq variable which is passed to a modal pop-up when selected.

Depending on the value of CarersReq for any record selected I want to either show or hide a div in the modal dynamically (eg the div will show in the popup where the selected record has CarersReq is more then 2 but would be hidden if not.

In tests where I debug through the code using Chrome's f12 window, I can see it picks up the correct variables and hits the if (CarersReq......) line but then skips to the end.

Is there a problem with my if statement?

**html**

```
<!-- Modal Book outside of Rota-->
<div id="modalBookOutsideRota" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Book outside of Rota</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Select a reason why this visit is being booked outside of Rota hours, then click Book.</p>
                <p><i>If the reason isn't listed select other and please give details in the box provided.</i></p>
                <br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReasons" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm m-b-10" DataSourceID="reasonSource" DataTextField="reason" DataValueField="OutOfRotaID"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="reasonSource" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNote" runat="server" CssClass="form-control overflow" placeholder="Note..."></asp:TextBox>
                <input name="sidInput" type="hidden" id="sidInput" runat="server" />
                <input name="carersReqInput" type="hidden" id="carersReqInput" runat="server" />

                <br />
                <div id="divSecondCarerControls">
                <p id="pSecondCarer">Select a second Carer that will help deliver the care.</p>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSecondCarer" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm m-b-10" DataSourceID="secondCarerSource" DataTextField="fullname" DataValueField="CarerID" Enabled="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="secondCarerSource" runat="server" />
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitBooking" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm" OnClick="btnSubmitBooking_Click" Text="Book" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn  btn-large">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function modalOutsideHours(sid, CarersReq) {
        document.getElementById('<%=sidInput.ClientID%>').value = sid;
        debugger;
        document.getElementById('<%=carersReqInput.ClientID%>').value = CarersReq;
        $('#ddlSecondCarer').change(function () {
            if (CarersReq > '1') {
                $('#divSecondCarerControls').show();
                alert("Show");
            } else {
                $('#divSecondCarerControls').hide();
                alert("Hide");
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed this problem was changing the line to `$('#ddlSecondCarer').ready(function () {`

Answer (score 4):

in your if, don't put quote around the one, it evaluates it as a string when you want to evaluate a number. Try this:

```
if (CarersReq > 1) {
```

Comment: Have tried taking the ' ' s out but it hasn't made a difference - still doesn't hide anything

Comment: @JoshCooper can you get value of CarersReq from console to make sure it's a number and that it has expected value.

Comment: The console says it is the expected number eg... 1

Comment: @JoshCooper are the alerts showing at all? Is it just the hiding not working or the whole if?

Comment: The alerts aren't firing either

Comment: @JoshCooper that's strange. What I would to at this point is just before your if statement, get console log for CarersReq > 1 and see if it gives you true or false. And maybe put the alert before you show and hide call, just to make sure it's not a problem with these also.

Comment: I've put more alerts in and looks to be a problem with the change event line, no alerts fire after that

Comment: @JoshCooper Just a hunch: since you've started without jquery, I'm wondering, did you include it in your header? And do you have any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

If you check CarersReq, you suppose it's Integer, but it doesn't have to be. Try `parseInt(CarersReq) > 1` in condition. (as other said, without quotes it is better)

Note: If you're using jQuery, why have you used `document.getElementById` instead of `$('#...')`?

Comment: 1 - Have ammended the line to if (parseInt(CarersReq) > '1') { but it hasn't changed anything. 2 - The document.get....was just a way I got it working so kept with it and while researching how to get this Q to work i found jQuery answers to went with that. Should that cause an issue?

Comment: Using document.get... shouldn't cause the problem... When call you the function `modalOutsideHours()`?

Comment: if it does parse, you definitely have an int and need parseInt(CarersReq) > 1 -- without the single quotes. What you should do is alert or console.out the value of CarersReq to see what it even is in that variable.

Comment: When testing in debug mode in chrome it reads CarersReq as being a 1 or a 2 depending on which record I select so I assume it is pulling the number in correctly

Comment: Isn't it strange? You want to hide elm after change elm inside that... `divSecondCarerControls` is parent node of `ddlSecondCarer`. Is this really you want to do?

Comment: The end result I want is for the <p> and <dropdownlist > to be hidden, I thought it would be neater to group these in a div and hide the div. The change was something I pulled from another answer - could that be a problem?

Comment: It's up to you if you group these elements, I would do it same. What makes no sense is hide parent node after changing child elm...

However - try again parseInt without quotes, as I edited... And try write exact events what browser does when you select item with 1 or 2...

Comment: Is event `change` really fired? Try write `console.log` or `alert` before if statement...

Comment: I've put alerts before and after the change event line and the alert before fires but not the alert after

Comment: Open console and write `$('#ddlSecondCarer')` - have you got this elm? does jQuery find them? Haven't you any errors in debug bar? Maybe you can't use change for that elm. How does it look like in final html? (what is the result of `<asp:DropDownList>`) Is there correct id?

Comment: When I type $('#ddlSecondCarer') into the console I just get back [], in the final html it looks fine. I just need to be able to hide it

Comment: If you got [], jQuery hasn't found this elm... Write to your question also final html and place where you call function modalOutsideHours()... And once again - do you think, that it makes sense to hide parent node and expect to be shown if something has changed? How could it be changed when it is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

In this line `if (CarersReq > '1')` you are comparing with a string not number. To make it a number you need to loose the quotes. It should be `if (CarersReq > 1)`

Comment: Have tried taking the ' ' s out but it hasn't made a difference - still doesn't hide anything

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using conditional operator inside if condition, you must use numeric value to the right side of `if` condition. Use `CarersReq > 1` inside if condition.

Comment: Try to check the value of `CarersReq` using a JS alert. Hope it is not 1 as expected.